# Can't understand Grape API route param

Tags: ruby, routes, grape-api

I am having a lot of trouble understanding Grape API, specifically `route_param` and how it works with just `params`.

Consider this code:

```
desc "Return a status."
params do
 requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "Status id."
end
route_param :id do
 get do
  Status.find(param[:id])
 end
end
```

What route does this block produce? I get that this is a `get` request, but why is it wrapped in `route_param` block? Why can't it be in `params` block?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your block produces this route:

```
http://yourdomain.com/<resource>/<id>
```

Note that your code and the code below do the same thing and produce the same route:

```
desc "Return a status."

params do
  requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "Status id."
end

get ':id' do
  Status.find(params[:id]) 
end
```

You can use `route_param` to group methods that receive the same params, for example:

```
resource :categories do
  route_param :id do
    get do # produces the route GET /categories/:id
    end

    put do # produces the route PUT /categories/:id
    end
  end
end
```